# How to reset RatingBar with button click

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ratingBar and a button and want to reset the rating with a button click. The code looks like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  
  const HomeScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  RatingBar ratingBar = RatingBar.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(
      Icons.star,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
      print(rating);
    },
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ratingBar,
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ratingBar.onRatingUpdate(0.0);
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Text('Reset'))
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

When the Reset button is clicked, `0` is printed, but the rating bar is still showing the rating that was previously selected by the user.

How do I get the ratingBar back to `0` on the click of a button?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the fix. You provide the data inside `setState()` that you want to change.

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    ratingBar.onRatingUpdate(0.0);
  });
},
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This does not work for me, the rating bar is not updated when I click the reset button.

Comment: I have the same problem. I just can't set it to zero (reset) after I submit the form. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
  double rating = 0.0;
```

//RatingBar function

```
  RatingBar.builder(
          initialRating: rating,
          minRating: 1,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          allowHalfRating: true,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemSize: 40,
          itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
            Icons.star,
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          onRatingUpdate: (value) {
            setState(() {
              rating = value;
            });
          },
        ),
```

//Reset button

```
 ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Reset the rating to 0.0
            setState(() {
              rating = 0.0;
            });
          },
          child: Text('Reset Rating'),
        ),
```